# Mid 2014 MBP w/ Nvidia to three 60in HD TVs?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

For a project I am working on, I'd like to connect my MBP to three 60in TVs.

I've read that it is possible to hook up to three external displays via these configurations:

2012 MBPR with extra graphics chip can drive 2x TB-DVI + 1x HDMI

2015 MBPR with extra graphics chip can NOT drive 2x TB-DVI + 1X HDMI but it CAN drive 1x TB-DVI + 1x TB-DisplayPort + 1x HDMI as one of the answers here indicates.

When reading around I've found that most people, when referring to external displays, are talking about displays that are in the 24-30in range. Is there any reason the configurations I stated above wouldn't work with three identical 60in HD TVs?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the resolution of the TVs, not the size (inches).

Comment: Are you needing to display something different on each of the TVs?

Comment: Yes, I need to control all three screens individually.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that something that works with a 24" tv wouldn't work with a 60" tv of the same resolution. Size doesn't matter - only resolution.